# How to redirect in a wordpress custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I used wp_redirect() and header() for redirection after handle post request, but i get this error "Headers already sent." Is there another method for redirection?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `wp_redirect()` is the way to go. Your issue is that some part of your plugin or template is already sending a response back to the client's browser, i.e. the headers are already sent.

You need to call `wp_redirect()` before sending anything else, and send only that.

There are a ton of ways your code could be sending headers before the redirect call. For example, the issue could be something as simple as having a newline or whitespace before a PHP open tag `<?php` that gets interpreted as content to send back to the client's browser. By the time the interpreter would hit the `wp_redirect()` line, the headers would already have been sent, making it impossible for `wp_redirect()` to send a redirect header.

More on HTTP redirects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

Note that it's common to follow a `wp_redirect()` line with an `exit;` line to ensure that WordPress/PHP execution stops and no further headers/content are sent back.